# How to insert data to mysql based on given condition?

Tags: php, mysql

Well, I am inserting data to `client_pay_bill` table if client pay his running monthly bill.

So for e.g;

Today is 2016-08-29.

If Client bill is `700` and he paid more than his monthly bill e.g `1800` then I want to divided this `1800 / 700`. So   `pay_amount`, `bill_month` and `due_amount` column data will be insert 3 times in following way :

**table : clients_pay_bill**

```
pay_amount    bill_month     due_amount
=======================================
700           2016-08-29     0
700           2016-09-29     0
400           2016-10-29     0
```

Otherwise If he paid only monthly bill `700` or less then `700` I want to run my `else` statement.

So for that I can't determine how the query should look like. Bellow is my code (Not finished)

```
$entry_date = time();

if($advance_amount >  $monthly_bill) {

    $counting_month = round($advance_amount / $monthly_bill);
    $advance_amount .= $ad;

    for ($x=0; $x<=$counting_month; $x++) {
        $r = $advance_amount - $monthly_bill;                       
        $ad = $r;

        $insert_to_month = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO     
        clients_pay_bill (client_id, pay_amount, bill_month, receipt_no, 
        entry_date, uid, remark) VALUES('$client_id', '', '', '', '', '', 
        '' ) ");
    }
} else {
    $insert = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO clients_pay_bill (client_id, 
    pay_amount, discount_amount, due_amount, advance_amount, bill_month, 
    receipt_no, entry_date, is_paid, uid, remark) VALUES('$client_id', 
   '$paid_amount', '$discount_amount', '$due_amount', '$advance_amount', 
   '$bill_month', '$receipt_no', '$entry_date', '1', '$uid', '$remark'  ) 
"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
 $entry_date = date("Y-m-d");

if($advance_amount >  $monthly_bill) {

$counting_month = round($advance_amount / $monthly_bill);
$advance_amount .= $ad;

for ($x=0; $x<=$counting_month; $x++) { //This loop will run for 700 700
    $r = $advance_amount - $monthly_bill;                       
    $ad = $r;
    $forOdNextMonth= date('m', strtotime("+".$x." month", strtotime($entry_date )));
    $insert_to_month = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO     
    clients_pay_bill (client_id, pay_amount, bill_month, receipt_no, 
    entry_date, uid, remark) VALUES('$client_id', '$monthly_bill;', '$forOdNextMonth', '$receipt_no', '$entry_date', '$uid', '$remark' ) ");
}if($r>0){ //This loop will run for remaining amount 400 as amount will be 1800

$forOdNextMonth= date('m', strtotime("+".($x+1)." month", strtotime($entry_date )));
 $insert_to_month = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO     
    clients_pay_bill (client_id, pay_amount, bill_month, receipt_no, 
    entry_date, uid, remark) VALUES('$client_id', '$r', '$forOdNextMonth', '$receipt_no', '$entry_date', '$uid', '$remark' ) ");
 }
 } else {
$insert = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO clients_pay_bill (client_id, 
pay_amount, discount_amount, due_amount, advance_amount, bill_month, 
receipt_no, entry_date, is_paid, uid, remark) VALUES('$client_id', 
'$paid_amount', '$discount_amount', '$due_amount', '$advance_amount', 
'$bill_month', '$receipt_no', '$entry_date', '1', '$uid', '$remark'  ) 
"); 
}
```

TESTCODE as to DIVIDE money

```
<?php
$amount=1800;
$monthlybill=700;
for($i=0;$i<$amount/$monthlybill;$i++)
{
echo"paid for ".($i+1)." month =".$monthlybill."<br>";
$amount-=$monthlybill;
}
if($amount>0){

    echo"paid for ".($i+1)." month =".$amount;
    }



?>
```

Comment: Thanks I am checking it.

Comment: Sorry, the condition will be `$paid_amount`. If `$paid_amount > $month_bill`. So I changed the` $advance_amount` to `$paid_amount` but showing me Undefined variable:` ad` in ...

Comment: through your code `$advance_amount ` means amount payable passed by the client, how to you pass through `POST` or how?

Comment: Now. may be I can do this but only problem is : 700, 700, 300 if user paid 1800. So can you show me a loop which echo this broken amount. ?

Comment: i added comment where it will be executed

Comment: if user pay 1400 `$r` will be `0` and it will not run if amount id 1401 it will run for 1

Comment: Not working. Can you just show me a `for` or `while` loop which will show : 700, 700, 400 to each line if $main number is 1800 ?

Comment: `for ($x=0; $x<=$counting_month; $x++) { ` this will run for all $monthly_bill multiple in your case 700 if any amount left will be covered in `if($r>0){`

Comment: It's asking me undefine $ad. But can you show me a different simple for loop which show 700, 700 and 400 to each line ?

Comment: Thanks a ton for your effort bro :)